# OSMNX: Street Network projection misses some of the initial nodes

Tags: graph, nodes, openstreetmap, osmnx

When I project the walking street network of Amsterdam I miss some of the nodes of the initial graph.

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox

G_wgs84 = ox.graph_from_place('Amsterdam',retain_all=True, network_type='walk')
G = ox.project_graph(G_wgs84, to_crs='epsg:28992')
```

Nodes of **G_wgs84** = **45960**

Nodes of **G** = **45936**

An identified example of a node existing in G_wgs84 but not in G is 7394240355.

Is there any logical explanation of why some nodes exist in the initial graph but not in the projected one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the exact same number of nodes when I run your code snippet:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True)
print(ox.__version__)  # prints v1.1.1
G1 = ox.graph_from_place('Amsterdam', retain_all=True, network_type='walk')
G2 = ox.project_graph(G1, to_crs='epsg:28992')
print(len(G1.nodes), len(G2.nodes))  # prints 46079 46079
```

Comment: Hmm this is interesting... What I figured out is that the nodes that I am missing in the projected graph are the isolated ones. So if before I project my graph I run:
    G_wgs84.remove_nodes_from(list(nx.isolates(G_wgs84)))

I get the same number of nodes (45936). Cannot understand why you get different results.

Comment: What version of OSMnx are you using?

Comment: Hmm indeed the version was the issue, I was using 1.0.1. I upgraded it and got the same results ass you.  I will probably need to redo the analysis in case other things have also gone wrong then. Thank you very much for the help! I really like using osmnx and your examples are very nice!